# MSBuild update, where dos this come from?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Here is the context :

- 2 persons are working on a WPF application (me and a colleague)
- we both use the VS 2017 (i have the version 15.6.6 he has the version 15.6.4)
- we are both using the most recent and fully updated .NET Framework
- we are using MSI installation system to deploy our WPF application + Win services
- we are using WIX to package all this

But something strange happened: when I generate the installer, the netstandard.dll version deployed is the 4.6.25908.2, and when he generates the installer, the netstandard.dll is the 4.6.26011.1

After some research, we discover that this dll is coming from MSBUILD, and by checking in the "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017", using the "msbuild" command :
- my version is 15.5.180.xxxx
- his version is 15.6.6.xxxx

My question is pretty simple, what is responsible for updating msbuild package?

Obviously, not VS or .Net Framework

I have found some nugget package to add to my projects but I don't want this, I want this dll to be updated properly in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib" directory

How can I manage to achieve this?

Comment: In general, Microsoft advice here, it's best business practice to make sure you're all on the same version and SP level. Especially a product as complex as VS2017.

Comment: Well, it is nothing unusual.  Microsoft switched their agile development process into overdrive at VS2017.  MSBuild and .NETStandard are similarly affected, the desktop version of the framework is not.  Updates are delivered through the VS2017 installer.  The 15.6.x versions were particularly short-lived, the first ones had many bugs.  There is no decent way to track these updates, Microsoft no longer documents exactly what gets updated.  You can only compare notes with your colleague if you also update to 15.6.6

Comment: So according to you, MSBUILD is installed/managed/updated by VS 2017 ?

Comment: @Jeremy : this is just impossible... and this thread is the proof of it : even when you think you have similar installations, by checking inner dll versions of all .Net related libs, you will see some differences no matter what. As i said in my post, all auto updates you can humanly imagines on our machines are enabled... what else can we do ?

Comment: You could use a build server to generate your final deliverable, so this sort of difference doesn't matter. Some software houses have a standard dev build. This is updated regularly and built into a virtual machine. All developers work using vm with this one build.  Not terribly efficient but when something weird happens with your dev env you just junk the vm file and copy a new version.

Comment: Yea I know some companies who build their business only on VM providing for IT Teams, I'm not sure this the way I want, but it could be something to consider. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found what was going on and there was no way to find out with what I posted.

This is the story :

- I installed VS 2017 Pro with a license
- I tried VS 2017 Enterprise for sometimes with a trial license
- VS 2017 setup made 2 distinct installations
- After the trial license expired, I was still using then Enterprise installation downgraded to a Pro version
- The Enterprise version was up to date but not the original Pro version

Conlusion: by updating the VS 2017 Pro version specifically, it solved my problem

@Hans Passant: the MSBUILD was indeed updated with VS 2017, but for some reason, I don't really understand, I have to update both Pro and Enterprise version to 15.6.6.xxxx in order to update MSBUILD properly